# How do I configure alembic.ini path correctly?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic

When I run any alembic commands, I get the following error:

FAILED: No config file 'alembic.ini' found, or file has no '[alembic]' section

According to the documentation, I need to set my path so I did. I'm running WSL Ubuntu 18.

Am I setting the path wrong? I run the commands in my flask project's top directory:
`~/microblog$`

My alembic file structure is:

```
~/microblog/
 - migrations/
  -- __pycache__/
  -- versions/
  -- alembic.ini
  -- env.py
  -- README
  -- script.py.mako
```

alembic.ini

```
# A generic, single database configuration.

[alembic]
script_location = home/acanizales1/microblog/migrations/alembic
# template used to generate migration files
# file_template = %%(rev)s_%%(slug)s

# set to 'true' to run the environment during
# the 'revision' command, regardless of autogenerate
# revision_environment = false


# Logging configuration
[loggers]
keys = root,sqlalchemy,alembic
... the rest below are configured correctly ...
```

Thank you.

Comment: Following up. Any ideas?

Comment: I usually do `PYTHONPATH=. alembic ...`, assuming I'm in the same directory as alembic.ini